# Html- I have two multiple select boxes and a label

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the value of the label when I select two values(one from each multiple select box) Like option1 from box1 and option2 from box2 and the label value changes.

```
<select id="opt1" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>

<select id="opt2" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
    <option value="4">Opt 4</option>
</select><br />

<label id="changeme">This should change</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly it may be like that

```
var s1_t = 'N/A';
var s2_t = 'N/A';

$('#opt1').change(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var val = $this.val();
  s1_t = val ? $this.find("option[value=" + val + "]").text() : 'N/A';
  $('#changeme').text(s1_t + ' - ' + s2_t)
});

$('#opt2').change(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var val = $this.val();
  s2_t = val ? $this.find("option[value=" + val + "]").text() : 'N/A';
  $('#changeme').text(s1_t + ' - ' + s2_t)
});
```

Your updated sample [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/61ed0t6j/3/)

Comment: thank you for your response. What I exactly want is: opt1 and opt2 are locations and when I select two options(one from each), label would show the distance between them. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```js
var FLAG1=0;
function update(){
  if(FLAG1==0){
    FLAG1=1;
  }
  else{
    var ct=document.querySelectorAll('select');
    document.getElementById('changeme').innerHTML=ct[0].value+"-"+ct[1].value;
    FLAG1=0;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="opt1" multiple="multiple" onchange="update();">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="opt2" multiple="multiple" onchange="update();">
        <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
        <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
        <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
        <option value="4">Opt 4</option>
    </select><br />

<label id="changeme">This should change</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with something like this

```
var label = document.getElementById("changeme");
var opt1 = document.getElementById("opt1");
var opt2 = document.getElementById("opt2");

opt1.onchange = function() {
  label.textContent = opt1.value + "-" + opt2.value;
}

opt2.onchange = function() {
  label.textContent = opt1.value + "-" + opt2.value;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/61ed0t6j/6/